# How do I prove $\frac{\sin x + \csc y}{\sin y + \csc x} = \csc y \sin x$?

Tags: trigonometry

How do I prove $\frac{\sin x + \csc y}{\sin y + \csc x} = \csc y \sin x$?

I managed to get to $\frac{\sin^2x\sin y+1}{\sin^2y\sin x+1}$ from the left hand side and then got stuck.

Comment: Is it $\frac{\sin(x)+\csc(y)}{\sin(y)+\csc(x)}=\csc(y)\sin(x)$?

Comment: No, it is as I posted.

Comment: I think you made a mistake in your manipulation. I think you should have $\frac{\sin^2 x \sin y + \sin x}{\sin x \sin^2 y + \sin y}$. This is obtained by multiplying the numerator and denominator by $\sin x \sin y$.

Comment: Oh yes thank you, I did.

Comment: Then it becomes really easy. should I delete the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\csc{(y)}\sin{(x)}
&=\csc{(y)}\sin{(x)}\cdot\frac{\sin{(y)}+\csc{(x)}}{\sin{(y)}+\csc{(x)}}\\
&=\frac{\csc{(y)}\sin{(x)}\sin{(y)}+\csc{(y)}\sin{(x)}\csc{(x)}}{\sin{(y)}+\csc{(x)}}\\
&=\frac{\sin{(x)}+\csc{(y)}}{\sin{(y)}+\csc{(x)}}\\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

If $\sin x=p,\sin y=q$

$\dfrac{p+\dfrac1q}{q+\dfrac1p}=\dfrac pq$ if $pq+1\ne0$

Answer (score 0):

The left-hand side is given by
$$\frac{\sin(x)(1+\sin(x))}{\sin(y)(1+\sin(x))}$$